# Issue occurred when using constructor-prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-pattern

In the below code, I would like to create a table. I have created the table with ppCreateTable() function. But I am unable to access row() function.
Can someone tell me how to access row() function?

```
var ppElement=function(str_elmt){
      this.tagName=str_elmt;
      return this.ppCreate();
    };
    ppElement.prototype={
      constructor:ppElement,
      ppCreate:function(){
        return document.createElement(this.tagName);
      },
      ppAppend:function(){
        var prntObj=arguments[0];
        for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
          prntObj.appendChild(arguments[i]);
        }
      },
      ppSetStyle:function(){
       var prntObj=arguments[0];
        prntObj.style.cssText=arguments[1];
      },
     ppWrapper:function(){
       var wrapper_Obj=ppElement.call(this,"div");
       var child_Obj=[];
        child_Obj[0]=wrapper_Obj;
       for(var i=0,j=1;i<arguments.length;i++,j++){
         child_Obj[j]=arguments[i];
       }
        this.ppAppend.apply(this,child_Obj);
        return wrapper_Obj;
     }
    };

    var ppTable=function(row_int,coloumn_int){
    this.row=row_int;
    this.coloumn=coloumn_int;
    return this.ppCreateTable();
    };
    ppTable.prototype=Object.create(ppElement.prototype,{
      constructor:ppTable,
      ppCreateTable:{
        value:function(){
          var tableObj=ppElement.call(this,"div");
          for(var i=0;i<this.row;i++){
           var tableRowObj=ppElement.call(this,"div");
           for(var j=0;j<this.coloumn;j++){
            var tableColumnObj=ppElement.call(this,"div");
            this.ppAppend(tableRowObj,tableColumnObj);
           }
          this.ppAppend(tableObj,tableRowObj);
         }
         return tableObj;
       }
     },
    tableCell:{
     value:function(){
       alert("hi");
     }
    }
    });

    var testTable=new ppTable(2,2);
    testTable.tableCell();
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(testTable);
```

Comment: `I am unable to access row() function` - why? what happens? you do realise you have `this.row = row_int` in the constructor?

Comment: Oops!! I never noticed that. Thanks for your notification @Jaromanda X. Now I have updated the `row()` function to `tableCell()` but still it is not working. @Jaromanda X

Comment: what doe `ppElement.prototype` look like? also, are there any errors in the console, because I tried a very basic version of your code (used `{}` instead of `ppElement.prototype` in `Object.create` and it worked fine

Comment: Now you can see the `ppElement()` funtion. This was the code I was running. I don't get any other errors in the console except `Uncaught TypeError: testTable.tableCell is not a function` error. @Jaromanda X

Comment: When I use `return this.ppCreateTable();` in `ppTable()` I get `Uncaught TypeError: testTable.tableCell is not a function` error. But when I remove that line it works. I would like to create a table when I add `var testTable=new ppTable(2,2);` so I wrote a written statement in the `ppTable` constructor.

Comment: Oh I see now ... in the constructor you `return this.ppCreateTable();` ... so testTable is the div returned by `return this.ppCreateTable();`

Comment: Yes you are right @Jaromanda X.

Comment: there's a **lot** going wrong with that code - I think you really want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bc22ky3q/)

Comment: thank you so much @Jaromanda X. I read your updated code. Now I am writing my code in the similar manner.